# Site logo, utility menu and search box. Template or all css?

Tags: theming

In the header, I would like to have a site logo on the left, utility menu in the middle and a search box on the right.

Should I just insert the utility menu as a block and style the rest via css? Or should I add regions or anything to the page template first and then style using css?

Comment: Are you using a custom theme or some theme that you have downloaded

Comment: I am uzing a Zen theme.